# Draw a circle based on two points

Tags: math, mfc, geometry, 2d

I have two points with their coordinates and have to draw a circle. One point is the center and the other one is on the edge of the circle, so basically the distance between the two points is the radius of the circle. I have to do this in MFC. I tried this, but the circle is not drawn properly. Usually it's bigger than it should be.

```cpp
double radius = sqrt((c->p1.x*1.0 - c->p1.y) * (c->p1.x - c->p1.y) +
                     (c->p2.x - c->p2.y) * (c->p2.x - c->p2.y));

CPen black(PS_SOLID,3,RGB(255,0,0));
pDC->SelectObject(&black);

pDC->Ellipse(c->p1.x-radius , c->p1.y-radius, c->p1.x+radius, c->p1.y+radius);
```

`p1` and `p2` are points. The circle is drawn as an incircle in a rectangle. The arguments in `Ellipse()` are the top left and bottom right corners of a rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your radius computations is wrong ... it should be:

```cpp
double radius = sqrt(((c->p2.x - c->p1.x)*(c->p2.x - c->p1.x))
                    +((c->p2.y - c->p1.y)*(c->p2.y - c->p1.y)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation to calculate the radius, that's easier to read (and correct):

```cpp
#include <cmath>

int findRadius( const CPoint& p1, const CPoint& p2 ) {
    // Calculate distance
    CPoint dist{ p2 };
    dist -= p1;
    // Calculate radius
    double r = std::sqrt( ( dist.x * dist.x ) + ( dist.y * dist.y ) );
    // Convert to integer with appropriate rounding
    return static_cast<int>( r + 0.5 );
}
```

You can use this from your rendering code:

```cpp
int radius = findRadius( c->p1, c->p2 );
CPen black( PS_SOLID, 3, RGB( 255, 0, 0 ) );
// Save previously selected pen
CPen* pOld = pDC->SelectObject( &black );
pDC->Ellipse( c->p1.x - radius, c->p1.y - radius,
              c->p1.x + radius, c->p1.y + radius );
// Restore DC by selecting the old pen
pDC->SelectObject( pOld );
```